# jQuery UI dialog positioning woes -- "append" statement question

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, append, css-position

Hey Guys -- I'm using a jQuery UI dialog box on my site but it's using absolute positioning and I need relative. My solution is to wrap the dynamically created DIV in a relatively positioned element.

I found the line of code I need to change but I think my change is affecting the "container" variable and breaking the remainder of the code. Does anyone know the best way to change this:

```
        function initialize(instance) {
        _this = instance;
        // build html
        var realCaller = caller != null? caller:$("body");
        var cornerClass = options.showRoundCorner? "ui-corner-all ":"";
        realCaller.append("<div id='"+windowId+"' class='window_panel "+cornerClass+options.containerClass+"'></div>");
        container = realCaller.children("div#"+windowId);
```

to add "`<div class=window_container>`" on the "append" line, like this:

```
        function initialize(instance) {
        _this = instance;
        // build html
        var realCaller = caller != null? caller:$("body");
        var cornerClass = options.showRoundCorner? "ui-corner-all ":"";
        realCaller.append("<div class=window_container><div id='"+windowId+"' class='window_panel "+cornerClass+options.containerClass+"'></div></div>");
        container = realCaller.children("div#"+windowId);
```

I don't know why it's breaking the rest of the script but I assume it's something to do with the way the "container" is being created and referenced by the rest of the JS.

Been working on this for over 8 hours now.. anyone can help!?

I can provide more details if necessary.

Cheers!

Comment: Why does the dialog box need relative positioning? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Check it out http://www.freemanfoxx.com/2home  -- after the page loads if you change the width your browser window it eventually screws up the positioning of the div in which the absolutely positioned "FreemanFoxx Updates" window is placed. I'm trying to pop this dynamically created window into a new div to keep it positioned relative to the browser regardless of any change in size

Comment: another possibility is to just change the way the `<script>` renders the HTML so that rather than appending it to the end of a particular table (as is done now) it renders it inline where I specify with the `<script>` tag in the HTML, but I'm not sure how to do that either..

Comment: Well, this is really not how jQuery UI dialogs are meant you be used, but you can start cobbling it together simply by applying `position: relative;` to the `div#window_0`. Do this with a higher-specificity CSS selector than `.window_panel` (which is where the `position: absolute;` comes from).

Comment: I tried that, Matt, but then there is some crazy positioning going on that makes the box jump to the bottom of the screen.. (left: 1400 top:528) .. I have no clue where it's coming from.. Any thoughts on just changing the way the dynamically created HTML attaches to the main HTML? That might be a better workaround for me..